# Facebook oauth returns 2 fb ids for one user

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have been maintaining a site that allows users to login using the FB credentials. For the last 2 years this has all been working fine on our servers, still works fine actually.

Now I have added a new integration server. When a user logs in with their FB credentials a different ID is returned, different from the ID they get when they log into our older servers.

When i use either ID in facebook.com i get sent to the proper home page. So it looks like a user has more than one FB ID.

Has anyone seen this before? I am stumped. Have copied the working Facebook app definitions for the older servers, no joy. Stripped down the app definition for the new server, no joy.

One difference is that our new server is using an IP address, not a dns entry. Could that be the problem?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of API v2.0, Facebook has made user ids *app-scoped* – meaning, each app will see a different app-scoped id for a user. Purpose is of course to improve user privacy.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

And before you ask: No, you can not get the “real” id from an app-scoped one – and you’re not supposed to.

If you need to identify users across different apps owned by your company, see what it says about the Business Mapping API (litte bit further down in the changelog.)

Comment: Thanks this information helped a lot. Unfortunately we have users who first logged in before April 2014 so some people are still getting different app-scoped ids. Guess I will have to change our code to use the business mapping rules.

Comment: For users that logged in to an app for the first time before API v2.0 was introduced, you will still get their “global” user id. Only for users that logged in for the first time _after_, your app will get to see an app-scoped user id.